# Illustrator "Maintain Height & Width proprotions" error while rescaling

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a simple circle. As you can see some weird error appears. Thank you for help!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried creating a new doc and copying just that object to a new doc to see if the same issue happens?

Comment: @WELZ Okaaay, after a couple of "new docs" it now works fine. And the bad thing is i dont know what i've done. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Probably some setting within that document, lots of possibilities.

Comment: Rounding error in Illustrator... *exceptionally* common. If Align to Pixel Grid is active it *might* cause this, but 4px is *way* more than the Pixel Grid would cause.

Comment: @Scott Yes, i am aware, i've tried this by disabling grid and snapping and it is not the cause :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @WELZ mentioned in the comments, there can be "lots of possibilities".

Creating a new doc helped - it cleared away any other doc-specific settings which may have been causing the problem.